# How to put a field with the last numbered page in Ms Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

Academics text like monograph, dissertation and thesis sometimes use different pages' numbering  from pre-text, text, and post-text.

Then I need create [catalogue card](http://www.nzdl.org/gsdl/collect/fnl2.2/archives/HASH01a1/51ac3343.dir/p027.gif) with pre-text and text number of pages discriminated. For this I think I could put a field with the last page of the pre-text part and the last page numbered of the document (It isn't `{NUMPAGES}` because this give me the total pages number)

This is the structure of the document for understand better what is the problem:

1. Pre-text numbering start at the third page with roman numbering (iii) and ends at the end of the list of figures at the (xvi). This page in absolute numbering is also 16.
2. After the text part starts with the numbering with 1 (in Arabic Numbering), but in the absolute numbering of the document this is the 17 page. Then this numbering ends with the page 120 but in absolute numbering that page is 136.

Then I need a field that print XVI and 120. 
I could do this:

```
{={NUMPAGES}-16}
```

But if the pre-text increases pages, that won't work

I'll grateful with a solutions in VBA too.

Comment: Have you written a VBA code already? It is generous of you to " `accept solutions with VBA too` "

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? This is not a script writing service.

Comment: sorry I don't speak very well english. I don't know how be kinder or polite. I wanted to say that I'll be happy and very grateful too if the solution is editing field or writing a VBA routine

Comment: No Guys. Sorry if I express myself bad. Well I think there is a easy way to resolve this problem editing fields. Certainly Someone can resolve this reasearching on internet about VBA. I can do this. But I think that is a very simple problem that maybe there is a solution with field from word. My intension with I ask for a VBA solution was if someone know the solution answer the question because for me it'll be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

normally in footers I recall the syntax is x of xx
where xx is the last page.

When you change format, from a Roman to Arabic , somewhere you add...
RestartNumberingAtSection

this is an example script that needs checking

On Error Resume Next

Const wdPageBreak = 7
Const wdPageNumberStyleUppercaseRoman = 1

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()

Set objSection = objDoc.Sections(1)
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

Set objPageNumbers = objSection.Footers(1).PageNumbers
objPageNumbers.NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleUppercaseRoman
objPageNumbers.ShowFirstPageNumber = FALSE
objPageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = TRUE
objPageNumbers.StartingNumber = 17
objPageNumbers.Add(1)

objSelection.TypeText "This is page 1."
objSelection.InsertBreak(wdPageBreak)
objSelection.TypeText "This is page 2."
objSelection.InsertBreak(wdPageBreak)
objSelection.TypeText "This is page 3."

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a field and a bookmark.

First, create a new bookmark at the right of the paragraph mark where you have your section break at the end of the pretext section (I've named it bkPretextEnd).

Then where you want your adjusted page calculation to show, instead of hard-coding 16 insert a reference to the page number of the bookmark (and change the field format to Arabic, so it doesn't "fail" because of the i page numbering in that section).

[image]